# Static Variables vs Config File for Embedded Device

Tags: python, json, micropython

So I am currently working on an embedded device project using MicroPython where CPU cycles and memory are at a premium (in this instance I only have 512k memory to play with) and wanted to find out what is more memory efficient when setting up configuration parameters for my project/device.

Typically in most of my projects I use a static class that contains all my global configuration variables that all areas of the project would use. These variables store things like file locations, timeouts, buffer sizes etc. Now I know Python does not have the exact same structure for this kind of static/singleton class like in Java/C# but I have been using a single module file that acts very similar.

Now my questions comes to this; I currently load all my configuration values from a JSON file and load it using the ujson library (https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/ujson.html). The end result is I get a json object that I can use to assign my variables like so:

```
ISDEBUG     = json["global"]["isdebug"]
BUFFER_SIZE = json["comms"]["buffersize"]
TIMEOUT     = json["comms"]["timeout"]
```

Given I am trying to minimize memory usage as much as possible, would it be simpler/more efficient not to use a "static" class/variables and just refer to the json object whenever I need to access a configuration item?

Readability and prior experience on bigger projects makes me want to have a cleaner "static" configuration file/module/class but I wonder if I am double-handling here for no real reason especially when I want to minimize the footprint as much as possible. But on the other hand I don't know if the JSON object would take up more memory given it is a dictionary of dictionaries and not sure how to test the difference without spending the time implementing both ways.

Grateful any advice or best practice in this situation.

Comment: Firstly you will need to measure how much memory is being taken at various stages of the program running. If you cannot, there is very little you can do. Either way, if the `json` object is very large, I suspect the keys to the dictionaries might account for a large proportion. You will need to make sure the json is disposed of: Perform `json = None` after initialisation.

Comment: @quamrana Yeah, so I am already doing everything you have suggested so far such as checking memory at different points using both options and disposing at the end.

Just was not sure if there was a better way than to "manually" check. At least having your comment on the same wavelength of my current thinking gives me some confidence I am doing something right :)